Docker entrypoint curl api returns the same response all the time
I would request your kind assistance about this weird issue.
So basically I have a docker image, that starts with an entrypoint, which starts a loop to check an api with curl like this:
check_server_version() {
    if [ "$UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS" -eq 1 ]; then
        return 0
    fi

    local current_version=$(get_game_version)
    if [ -z "$current_version" ]; then
        log_message "Failed to get game version from steam.inf" "error"
        return 1
    fi

    local api_url="https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/UpToDateCheck/v0001/?appid=730&version=$current_version&nocache=$(date +%s)"
    local response=$(curl -s \
        -H "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store" \
        -H "Pragma: no-cache" \
        "$api_url")

    local up_to_date=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.response.up_to_date')

    if [ "$up_to_date" = "false" ]; then
        local required_version=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.response.required_version')
        local message=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.response.message')

        if [ ! -z "$required_version" ]; then
            log_message "New version detected: $required_version (current: $current_version)" "running"
            log_message "Steam message: $message" "running"

            if [ -z "$UPDATE_COUNTDOWN_TIME" ]; then
                UPDATE_COUNTDOWN_TIME=300
            fi

            log_message "Countdown initiated to restart server: $UPDATE_COUNTDOWN_TIME seconds" "running"

            if [ ! -z "$UPDATE_COMMANDS" ]; then
                start_update_countdown "$required_version"
            fi
        else
            log_message "Failed to get required version from API response" "error"
            log_message "Full response: $response" "debug"
            return 1
        fi
    else
        log_message "Server up to date. Current version: $current_version (checked at: $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))" "debug"
    fi
}

version_check_loop() {
    while [ ${UPDATE_AUTO_RESTART:-0} -eq 1 ] && [ $UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS -eq 0 ]; do
        sleep "${VERSION_CHECK_INTERVAL:-300}"
        check_server_version
    done
}

When you start a container, it runs the check properly and if it detect a new version on startup or after that within a few minutes, it execute the update tasks. But when the server runs for a while and a new update is dropped (and I see in the api when running it on my pc) the console keep saying in the debug logs that "Yeah no updates, current version from api is xy" and returns the old version that is running on the server.
Why this could happen?
The project is available tho on GitHub for full script to understand better: https://github.com/K4ryuu/CS2-Egg
I tried to add extra param to the url, tried to use no-cache and so on. I tried to fake an api response on startup with a new version, which works on startup.
